# How to test performance of redis in AWS Elasticache?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, redis, amazon-elasticache

I want to test the Redis performance running in AWS ElastiCache.
I have tried `redis-benchmark` tool to test it in my local machine.
I need the same to test in ElastiCache but I believe there is no terminal access or `redis-benchmark` utility tool.

How can the `redis-benchmark` test be done for the redis in AWS ElastiCache?

Is there any other way to test the performance of the redis in ElastiCache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redis-benchmark` tool is included on redis installation. What you may do is; connecting to your redis cluster from ec2. This [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html) shows the steps to connect it from your ec2 instance.

Then you may connect to your instance like this;

```
redis-cli -h mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

Just like connecting to your cluster you may use

```
redis-benchmark -h mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

to benchmark your cluster. It will print something like this;

```
====== mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com ======
  100000 requests completed in 1.83 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

99.36% <= 1 milliseconds
99.83% <= 2 milliseconds
99.92% <= 3 milliseconds
99.95% <= 4 milliseconds
99.96% <= 5 milliseconds
99.97% <= 6 milliseconds
99.99% <= 7 milliseconds
100.00% <= 7 milliseconds
54585.15 requests per second
```

Comment: So I have to create a new EC2 instance, install redis and run the redis-benchmark?

Comment: @DeekshithHegde yes, it won't take long to launch a new one and make it ready. When you are done, you may terminate it. You can't connect from your local to Elasticache instance  because it doesn't have public IP address and so it cannot be accessed from outside the VPC.