# How do you use redis-benchmark util to fill up a redis cluster memory?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, redis, benchmarking, amazon-elasticache

So basically I have a redis cluster deployed in AWS (Elasticache cluster mode) and I'm trying to run a util/test to have it's available memory utilization to fill up past a threshold to test my auto scaling. I've heard that the built in redis-benchmark util can be used to achieve this task but I'm struggling to get any success with it. Anyone have experience with this?

Goal: Use either redis-benchmark or similar util to write random keys/values to redis to fill up roughly 6gb of memory storage.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redis-benchmark you may use `DEBUG POPULATE` command of Redis to fill it with dummy data. But since `DEBUG` is a restricted command in [AWS Elasticache Redis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html) (as we discussed in the comments), another option could be using a lua script to fill it with dummy data.

I wrote the following lua snippet(i know not super clean and i am not super familiar)

```
for i = 1, 1000 do
    a[i] = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
end

for i = 1, 50000 do
    redis.call("RPUSH", i, unpack(a))
end
```

What it does is to fill the redis with multiple lists with multiple elements within it. It fill around ~4.6 GB data in couple of seconds. You may edit the parameters(second loop's upper bound) to re-run again.

I chose `lists` instead of `sets` or `sorted sets` to enable duplicate elements. Even though you re-run the script, it will push to the same lists again and again.

After you connected to your cluster via `redis-cli`, you may execute the following command on cli

```
eval "local a={}  for i=1,1000 do  a[i] = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111' end for i=1, 50000 do redis.call('RPUSH', i, unpack(a)) end" 0
```

You need to access to your redis cluster within the vpc. I've explained the concepts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153242/2188922) before.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm sure some will find it helpful. Sadly AWS limits you and Elasticache has the DEBUG command disabled. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html

Comment: @Cythrex you are right, i totally forgot about restricted commands. i will check and update the answer sometime to achieve it with lua scripting.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. That's what has me stumped a bit at the moment

Comment: @Cythrex i've updated the solution, as i mentioned it is not super clean but it looks like working. hope it helps.

Comment: amazing, thank you!